# Create list of hex from string

Tags: python, python-3.x, codec

I am trying to convert a string into a list of hex:

```py
myString = b'abcdefghijh'

hex = codecs.encode(myString, "hex")
print(hex)
print(list(hex))
```

However this is giving me the result:

```
b'6162636465666768696a68'
[54, 49, 54, 50, 54, 51, 54, 52, 54, 53, 54, 54, 54, 55, 54, 56, 54, 57, 54, 97, 54, 56]
```

Can someone tell me why the 2 do not match?

Comment: Why would they match? While `bytes` are displayed in a string-like fashion, when you iterate a `bytes` object you get individual integers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the `bytes` object into a `str`:

```
import codecs
myString = b'abcdefghijh'

hex = codecs.encode(myString, "hex")

print(hex)
print(list(str(hex)[2:-1]))

b'6162636465666768696a68'
```

Output:

```
b'6162636465666768696a68'
['6', '1', '6', '2', '6', '3', '6', '4', '6', '5', '6', '6', '6', '7', '6', '8', '6', '9', '6', 'a', '6', '8']
```

*(Note I stripped off the `b'` and `'` on both ends of the `byte` object for the `list`.)*

---

UPDATE (credits to @MrFuppes):

It is a bad practice to name variables with names taken by built-in methods, so `hex` should be named to, say, `my_hex`.

You can use `map` to map a list of integers into a list of `hex`:

```
lst = list(map(hex, lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myString = b'abcdefghijh'
hex = codecs.encode(myString, "hex")
print(hex)
# b'6162636465666768696a68'
```

The output you see here is actually a bytes object of your hexadecimal representation. This means the first byte in this `hex` object is the ASCII byte representation of '6', the second byte is the ASCII byte representation of '1', etc.
Python translates this back to characters for you convenience when printing to the console.

So when you do:

```
print(list(hex))
# [54, 49, 54, 50, 54, 51, 54, 52, 54, 53, 54, 54, 54, 55, 54, 56, 54, 57, 54, 97, 54, 56]
```

The numbers you see are the integer representations of the above mentioned bytes (54 is the decimal ASCII code for character '6', 49 is the decimal ASCII code for character '1' etc.)